# Espaces avec la ponctuation : le point de suspension est-il une exception ?

Tags: typographie, ponctuation

Pour déterminer s'il faut mettre une espace avant (ou après) une ponctuation, le moyen mnémotechnique le plus utilisé est « lorsque la ponctuation est en plusieurs parties, on utilise l'espace ».

- Exemples de ponctuations sans espace : `.` `,` `(` `)`
- Exemples de ponctuations avec espace : `?` `!` `:` `;`

Qu'en est-il du point de suspension `…` ? Instinctivement j'écrirais

> Sinon…

Est-ce qu'il est plus correct d'écrire

> Sinon …

Remarquez que j'utilise bien ici le caractère « … » et non la triple occurrence du caractère « . ».

Comment: Pour info, « espace », lorsque ce mot désigne le caractère en typographie, est féminin.

Comment: @Bruno +1 pour cette découverte ahurissante...

Comment: @Bruno je suis tout autant ahuri que Romain par cette révélation typographique ! C'est noté !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Je cite *Le lexique des règles typographique en usage à l'imprimerie nationale* qui est considéré en France comme la référence en matière de typographie :

> les points de suspension :
>    - remplaçant le début d'un texte, sont suivis de l'espacement normal des mots dans la ligne,
>   - tenant lieu d'une fin de phrase ou de mot, sont collés à la dernière lettre,
>   - mis pour un mot unique, sont précédés et suivis de l'espacement normal.

Answer (score 4):

D'après ces sources :

- [la-ponctuation.com](http://www.la-ponctuation.com/points-suspension.html)
- [Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Points_de_suspension)
- [interpc.fr](http://www.interpc.fr/mapage/billaud/ponctua.htm) (qui donne également pas mal de références bibliographique)

il semble effectivement qu'il ne faille pas d'espace **avant** le caractère "..."

D'après le Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'Imprimerie nationale, cité dans l'article de Wikipedia, la seule exception est [...] qui représente une citation tronquée.

Answer (score 3):

J'ignorais le moyen mnémotechnique que tu cites, mais il ne s'applique vraisemblablement pas ici, car **les points de suspension ne doivent pas être précédés d'un espace**.

Je n'ai pas de référence plus précise que [celle de Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Points_de_suspension), mais il me semble avoir toujours vu cette graphie.