# Est-ce que l'espace avant les ponctuations forts est obligatoire ou optionnelle ?

Tags: ponctuation

On place toujours une espace avant les ponctuations forts. Enfin, presque toujours. Par exemple, dans le livre *French in Action* (page 8) ils n'utilisent pas cette espace :

> Mireille: Ah, bon? . . . Bon, excuse-moi, je suis pressée. Au revoir!

Est-ce que l'espace avant les ponctuations forts est obligatoire ou optionnelle ?

Comment: [Espace avant les ponctuations fortes ?](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/46/pourquoi-place-t-on-une-espace-avant-les-ponctuations-fortes-why-is-there-a) ; [Which space should one use before punctuation ?](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/590/which-space-should-one-use-before-punctuation-does-it-depends-on-the-technolog) ; [http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/espaces-avec-la-ponctuation-le-point-de-suspension-est-il-une-exception](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/espaces-avec-la-ponctuation-le-point-de-suspension-est-il-une-exception)

Comment: *Techniquement*, les questions sont différentes. La première se pose la question du pourquoi, la seconde se pose la question technique du caractère (à la Unicode) à employer pour représenter l’espace, la dernière enfin s’intéresse exclusivement à la question des points de suspension. Aucune ne se pose la question de « Est-ce obligatoire ? »

Comment: À savoir : les règles d'espacement peuvent être différentes d'une région du monde à l'autre; donc une règle peut être « obligatoire » dans une région, tout en étant plus flexible ou différente ailleurs.

Comment: Vous avez raison, @AlexandreVaillancourt. *L'office québécois de la langue française* suggère de [ne pas utiliser d'espacement](http://66.46.185.79/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2039) dans la plupart des cas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cela dépend fortement de ce que tu qualifies d‘« obligatoire ». L’usage d’une espace (fine et insécable) est systématique dans l’imprimerie francophone de qualité et il est probable que nombre d’utilisateurs trouveraient, sinon fautif, du moins étrange le fait de ne pas en user.

Voici cependant ce qu’en dit Jean-Pierre Lacroux dans son *Orthotypographie* dans [le paragraphe « Espaces » de l’article « Ponctuation » :](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-II/point_cardinal-proverbe.html#Ponctuation)

> Les anciens typographes étaient plus souples que les modernes. Ils savaient jouer avec les espaces liées à la ponctuation.
>   Lefevre 1883 : « On met une espace d’un point avant la virgule, le point-virgule, le point d’exclamation et le point d’interrogation, si la ligne où ils se trouvent est espacée ordinairement ; mais si elle est plus serrée, on se dispense d’en mettre avant la virgule, surtout lorsqu’elle est précédée d’une lettre de forme ronde. Le contraire a lieu, c’est-à-dire que l’on peut augmenter l’espace d’un demi-point avant ces diverses ponctuations, et surtout avant les points d’exclamation et d’interrogation, si la ligne est espacée plus largement. On ne met pas d’espace avant le point qui termine une phrase, ni avant le point abréviatif, ni avant les points suspensifs. »
>   La virgule a perdu son espace éventuelle. Resquiescat in pace ! En revanche, rien n’interdit de continuer à faire varier les espaces qui précèdent le point-virgule, le point d’exclamation et le point d’interrogation. Aujourd’hui, rares sont les compositeurs qui se donnent la peine de modifier au coup par coup les espaces insécables fixes qui précèdent la ponctuation haute. Dommage, car de très légères modifications — quasi imperceptibles — peuvent éliminer des coupures ou améliorer l’espace justifiante d’une ligne donnée.